# How to assign an ID but then delete if not used

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am unsure on how to do this 'best practice' wise.

I have a web application (asp.net VB) that connects to an MS SQL server 2012.  Currently when the page loads the app connects to a DB table and gets the last ID and adds 1 to it and displays this to the user.  When the user submits the form the new ID is saved to the DB.

The problem being the app may be opened by 2 users at the same time and therefore they will get assigned the same ref number which will cause problems when the data is saved.

How can I assign different numbers to different users if the app is opened at the same time without saving unnecessary data?

Comment: Couldn't you just use Identity column as the Id? It is auto-incrementing column. You don't have to worry about saving data to database. [IdentityProperty](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple solutions for this, I'll try to outline a few approaches. (I'll assume that you need to insert things into a DB that I'll call "orders".)

First of all, you can move the ID-generation to the moment when the order is actually inserted, and not at the moment when the user start to enter the data. That way, you do not generate an ID for a user that never completes the form. Also this scenario is easy to accomplish using autoincrementing values in sql server. You can, for example do:

```
-- create a table with an identity column
create table Orders (
    ID int identity(1,1) not null, 
    Description nvarchar(max) not null
);

-- insert values, without specifying the ID column
insert into Orders (Description) values ()

-- select the row back
-- returns 1, 'My First Order'
select * from Orders;
```

Another way to do this is to use [SQL Server Sequences](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx). These are things that do nothing except generate numbers in a row. They guarantee that the numbers won't be repeated, and always keep count of the current value, i.e.

```
-- create a sequence
create sequence OrderIdSequence 
start with 1
increment by 1;

-- get the next sequence value
select next value for OrderIdSequence
```

Comment: originally that's what I had, the number was created when the form was submitted.  The user asked for this to be changed and wanted the number generating when the form is created.

Comment: Use sequences then. The drawback is that there will be a gap each time the form is not submitted.